# How to pack/unpack tuples and list with use msgpack (generic solution for any object)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, msgpack

Here is some problem with pack/unpack tuples. As I know msgpack not distinguish between list and tuple and there is not hook to force list or tuple be ExtType. It generates frustrating problems.

Assume that I want do generic solution for all types of objects not only for Period - it is simple to assume that key should be fixed for Period but it is not want I want to do.

See simple example class with **__hash__** - nothing special:

```
import msgpack

class Period(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.key)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.key == self.key

def encode(o):
    if type(o) is Period:
        return msgpack.ExtType(0, msgpack.dumps(o.__dict__))

def decode_ext(code, data):
    if code == 0:
        o = Period.__new__(Period)
        o.__dict__ = msgpack.loads(data)
        return o

o = {Period((2016, 7)): 112, Period((2016, 8)): 231}

print o
s = msgpack.dumps(o, default=encode)
print s
o2 = msgpack.loads(s, ext_hook=decode_ext)
print o2
```

It generates problem during unpacking which cannot be solved easily I think:

```
C:\root\Python27-64\python.exe "C:/Users/Cezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/msgpack_learn/src/02_tuple_wrong_pack.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
{<__main__.Period object at 0x0000000002941668>: 231, <__main__.Period object at 0x0000000002941AC8>: 112}
  File "C:/Users/Cezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/msgpack_learn/src/02_tuple_wrong_pack.py", line 28, in <module>
��
    o2 = msgpack.loads(s, ext_hook=decode_ext)
 ��key������
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 139, in msgpack._unpacker.unpackb (msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:139)
 ��key���p
  File "C:/Users/Cezary Wagner/PycharmProjects/msgpack_learn/src/02_tuple_wrong_pack.py", line 8, in __hash__
    return hash(self.key)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do you have any idea how to reconstruct tuple to tuples and list to lists using msgpack if it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

For your objects, you would have to write hooks for   `dict` as well, this is because your keys `Period((2016,7))` etc are hashable ( being a tuple ) in the original object, get converted to list which is unhashable.
For your custom hooks, you can store the dict as tuples of key-value pairs,
i.e. `{Period((2016, 7)): 112, Period((2016, 8)): 231}` should be converted to `[(Period((2016, 7)), 112), (Period((2016, 8)), 231)]` first.

and convert them to dict while unpacking. That way the unhashable nature of lists will not come into picture.

Comment: unpacking a top-level list errors `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`